# Is it safe to host a client certificate and a key on a node server with heroku

Tags: node.js, security, ssl, heroku, https

I am tying to connect to a secure api that requires a client ssl certificate and a key. The remote api gave me both of them and I'm able to connect to this api with postman without any issues.

Now, I have a node.js server hosted on Heroku and I need to send the client certificate and key with each request.

My question is how do I host this client certificate and key safely? In some kind of a folder (doesn't sound safe)? do I need heroku to host them for me for security reasons?

For the sake of the question I already host them in a regular folder and can perform my requests easily.

I'm new to SSl but do implementing this suggested solution is what I need?
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#manually-upload-certificates.

This Heroku docs talk about making the server a secure endpoint for users so it isn't relevant for me as my understanding goes-  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#ssl-file-types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer by getting help from the Heroku support and by understanding better how to work with client certificate.

Eventually I have used environment variables to store the key and the certificate as a string.

Heroku support environment variables through their CLI and server setting.

Most answers online talking about receiving the certificate, my issue was where to store them to be sent to a remote secure API.

I hope somebody, will be able to use this answer.